# Action not rendered in Zend_Navigation output?

Tags: php, zend-framework, navigation

I pass the following array to:

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation($fullmenu);
                    $this->view->navigation()->setContainer($container);
```

The array (dumped with print_r):

```
   Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [label] => menu
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => menu
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [class] => settings hidden-xs hidden-sm
    )
    [1] => Array (
    [label] => Users
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => user
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [pages] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [label] => Add User
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => user
    [action] => create
    [resource] => 
    )
    [1] => Array (
    [label] => List Users
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => user
    [action] => list
    [resource] =>
    )
    [2] => Array (
    [label] => Audit Trail
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => user
    [action] => trail
    [resource] =>
    )
    )
    [class] => dropdown-toggle
    )
    [2] => Array (
    [label] => reports
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => reports
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [class] => settings hidden-xs hidden-sm
    )
    [3] => Array (
    [label] => tests
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => tests
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [class] => settings hidden-xs hidden-sm
    )
    [4] => Array (
    [label] => Services
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => services
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [class] => settings hidden-xs hidden-sm
    )
    [5] => Array (
    [label] => sports
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => sports
    [action] => index
    [resource] =>
    [pages] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [label] => Register New sports
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => sports
    [action] => register
    [resource] => portal:smme.register
    )
    )
    [class] => dropdown-toggle
    )
    )
```

But the menu is not rendered correctly in the output as the `href's` resulting don't show in the `action` in the `url`.

In other words, the register new sport only shows:
[Register New sports](/admin/sports)

So they are always of the form: /module/controller
eg. admin/users

Comment: Do you maybe have several routes defined? If so, you may want to add the correct route name to the elements within `$fullmenu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you registered several routes, you may want to include the route name used when rendering the urls:

```
function includeRouteName(array $menuItems) {
    return array_map(function($menuItem) {
        if (!empty($menuItem['pages'])) {
            $menuItem['pages'] = includeRouteName($menuItem['pages']);
        }
        return new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc($menuItem + array(
            'route' => 'default' // assuming you have a route named 'default'
        ));
    }, $menuItems);
}

$fullmenu = includeRouteName($fullmenu);
```